# AsyncTask doesn't show ProgressDialog in Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm using AsyncTask in my custom Dialog.
AsyncTask works fine in activity, but inside dialog doesn't show ProgressDialog.
Tried do privid context from dialog, from activity who showed dialog, app context.
Result is same: no ProgressDialog shown on my screen.

```
private class ClearCache_Task extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Integer>
{
private ProgressDialog progressBar;
private ArrayList<String> m_subfolders;
private final Context m_con;

public ClearCache_Task(Context con, ArrayList<String> subfolders)
{
        m_con = con;
        m_subfolders = subfolders;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(m_con);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressBar.setCancelable(false);
        progressBar.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressBar.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressBar.dismiss();
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params)
    {
        try
        {
          m_KFileStorage.ClearCache(m_subfolders);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(AppTag, e.toString());
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Post the code of your AsyncTask please.

Comment: Did you check in debuger, if onPreExecute is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for question.
I made mistake calling old code instead of calling asynctask.:)

Answer (score 0):

how you attached dialog to activity?

That's how I did it:

In Activity:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(Application.string(R.string.dialog_message) + "...");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

In AsyncTask:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mActivity.showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
}
```

More information about Dialog can be read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: I found mistake :) I forgot to replace m_KFileStorage.ClearCache( in my code with new ClearCache_Task().execute() :)